# Saving psql output to csv file

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv, psql, postgresql-copy

I have a query written in a file located at /path/to/query.  How can I save the output result to a csv file, without using COPY in the query?  I tried the following command, but the output file's fields are separated by " | ".

```
psql -U username -d dbname -f /path/to/query -o /path/to/output/file -F ','
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is not explained in the documentation, but the `-F` option requires  the `-A` option (unaligned table output) to work:

```
psql -U username -d dbname -f /path/to/query -o /path/to/output/file -F ',' -A
```

If you don't wish the headers in your csv, this means, without extra rows at the top and at the bottom, use the `-t`  option too.

```
psql -U username -d dbname -f /path/to/query -o /path/to/output/file -F ',' -A -t
```

From the help:

> -A, --no-align           unaligned table output mode
>   -F, --field-separator=STRING
>                              set field separator (default: "|")
>   -t, --tuples-only        print rows only

Comment: It works.  This is a little nit-picky, but how do I get rid of 2 extra lines: "SELECT <random number>" at the top and "(rows <number of rows>)" at the bottom?

Comment: If you want only tuples, without other rows at bottom and at the top, use the option -t: `psql -U username -d dbname -f /path/to/query -o /path/to/output/file -F ',' -A -t`.

Comment: I tried that.  I still saw "SELECT<random number">, though the row count at the bottom disappeared.

Comment: This comes from the query. Post in your question the content of the file with the sql code.